# Where to buy a judo uniform (judogi) in Tokyo

Tags: shopping, tokyo, sport

[Kodokan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodokan) sells a few judo uniforms, but does not have much choice nor stock, their job is not to sell judogi.

Is there a sort of big specialist store where people usually go buy their judogi, with several brands and many sizes and models? Must be ready-to-wear rather than by order, and accessible to foreign tourists.

[image: judogi keikogi judo kimono]

Comment: I kind of disagree with closing this as a shopping request. OP’s not looking for a *specific* judo uniform or a certain price but asks if (and where) there are specialist stores that Japanese would use — imho on-topic.

Comment: @Jan Even then, it's not about travel (it's a [boat programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about)-type question).

Comment: (Aka you can't just stick "in <foreign place>" to a question to make it about travel.)

Comment: Japan is a *shopping travel destination* for many people: Anime fans, zazen addicts, kobe meat lovers, and serious judokas. Are some local people also fan of anime/zazen/beef/judo: Yes, but a tourist is not in the same situation as a local person. A local person would typically buy through the judo club they belong to.

Answer (score 4):

I know we frown at link only answers but [here is the same question](https://www.reddit.com/r/judo/comments/31rkkr/buying_a_judogi_in_tokyo_lf_a_shop/) with many answers on Reddit. I have copy-pasted the relevant excerpts below.

---

> there's a budo shop down the street from the kodokan that sells
>   kusakura judogi as well as their own brand. the kodokan store also
>   sells judogi.
>
> i have bought from the shop down the road and they are fine, but as a
>   foreigner i suggest contacting the owner of [budo
>   export](http://www.budoexport.com) who is very helpful and can get
>   both
>   [kusakura](http://www.budoexport.com/kimono-kusakura-xsl-245_261.html)
>   and mitsuboshi judogi in adition to [his own
>   line](http://www.budoexport.com/judogi-japonais-seido-xsl-322_466.html).
>   all the brands have "club" models that are a lot cheaper.
>
> he can ship within japan and he also let me meet him and pick mine up
>   in person. great guy. he is french but his english and japanese are
>   very very good. use google translate on the website if you need to. 
>   don't go to the seido english site as that's only aikido stuff.

---

> I bought a kuSakura pants from the shop down the road from the
>   Kodokan, they were very friendly. They also sell some cool cloth with
>   kanji it for decorating the dojo. I liked the Kodokan shop on the 1st
>   floor though, they probably have everything he needs :)

---

> There's Sakuraya near Kodanshita Station
>   http://www.sakuraya.org/e_index.html
>
> Definitely check out Iwata Shokai as well.
>   http://iwataco.com/frame2e.html They were one of the earliest
>   suppliers to the Kodokan, which they are very near, and though their
>   dōgi are labelled aikidogi, they're actually judogi. (I am fairly
>   certain that the house brand dōgi sold by Budo Export and Tozando are
>   actually rebranded Iwata ones.)

---

> I went to the Isami store in Suidobashi (for a BJJ gi).  They have a
>   few different brands and if I remember they had a sister store down
>   the street with even more options.  Not sure on price though, the
>   Isami I bought was right around 30000 yen (but I think Isami is known
>   as a higher-end gi).  http://suidobashi-isami.com/  (BJJ, not judo)